# Making Progress View Visible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, xcode4

I'm working on a very simple iOS app to get me started programming. It's a tab based application, so there is a MainWindow.xib along with a FirstView.xib and SecondView.xib. All of this is happening in the first view. I want to add a Progress bar to the First View, and when I added the object it attached itself to FirstView.xib and shows up and lets me move it around. To test, the alpha is set at 1.00 and the progress is set at 0.5. Regardless of this, it doesn't show up no matter what I do. What am I doing wrong?

AppDelegate.m:

```
@synthesize window=_window;

@synthesize tabBarController=_tabBarController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_tabBarController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

FirstViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
NSTimer *stopWatchTimer;
NSDate *startDate;

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

    UILabel *label;
    UILabel *stopWatchLabel;
    UIProgressView *progressBar;
    UIButton *topButton;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *stopWatchLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressBar;
- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)onStopPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)onResetPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"


@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize progressBar;
@synthesize stopWatchLabel;


/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.*/
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setStopWatchLabel:nil];
    [topButton release];
    topButton = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Release any[progress release];
    progressBar = nil;
    [progressBar release];
    progressBar = nil;
    [self setProgressBar:nil];
    //retained subviews of the[self setProgressBar:nil];

    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

static NSInteger counter=0;
static NSInteger secs=0;
static NSInteger mins=0;
static NSInteger hrs=0;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [stopWatchLabel release];
    [label release];

    [topButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)updateTimer {
//updates the timer    }

    -(void)clearTimer {
//clears the timer        


}

-(void)stopTimer{
//stops the timer    }


- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender {
    //stopWatchLabel.text=@"Start Pressed";
    progressBar.alpha=1.0;
//run timer    }


- (IBAction)onStopPressed:(id)sender {
    [self stopTimer];
}

- (IBAction)onResetPressed:(id)sender {
    [self stopTimer];
    [self clearTimer];
}
@end
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you're doing wrong when we don't know what you're doing? It's much easier to help you if you post some code. Otherwise we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: You are either not adding FirstView's view controller to the tab controller or as Erik mentioned not adding the progress bar as subview of the FirstView. If you are doing that fine, we will need to see some more info like the code to understand the issue.

Comment: I added the code to the delegate and the view controllers. I can attach the .xib file somewhere as well if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to do with a view after it's been created: You have to add it as a subview of a visible view and set a proper frame.

Here's how to do that:

```
 [self.view addSubview:progressBar];
progressBar.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

**EDIT:** Probably completely unrelated to your question, but this is all wrong:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setStopWatchLabel:nil];
    [topButton release];
    topButton = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Release any[progress release];
    progressBar = nil;
    [progressBar release];
    progressBar = nil;
    [self setProgressBar:nil];
    //retained subviews of the[self setProgressBar:nil];

    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

You probably want it to look something like the following:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [self setStopWatchLabel:nil];
    [topButton release];
    topButton = nil;
    [label release];
    label = nil;
    self.progressBar = nil;
}
```

Make sure you understand what you did wrong. It's very important that you get this right or your app will leak and/or crash.

The rest of your code doesn't really do anything. You seem to be doing everything in IB, so I guess that's where your problem is.

Comment: I see the three buttons and the Label in the First View, do I need to make a new view for just the progress bar?

Comment: +1 for the effort. @Laxsnor, if you've done everything in IB make sure your `UIProgressView` is a subview of the `UIView` set to the `view` outlet of `FirstViewController`. As long as the `UIProgressView` isn't hidden or transparent there's nothing else you need to do to simply see it in your app. Erik's comments on `viewDidUnload` are correct. Good luck.

Comment: Where should I set UIProgressView to be a subview of the view outlet of FirstView Controller?
Right now I have it doing the following in FirstViewController.h viewDidLoad: 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    progressBar=[progressBar initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
    [self.view addSubview:progressBar];
    [progressBar setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];

Comment: My comment was using the assumption that you were doing everything in IB. If you are creating the UIProgressView programmatically in `viewDidLoad` then you can ignore what I said. The code you have there should work and you'll see the progressBar. If you're not, something else is wrong. First, make sure that you do not have the progressBar in your XIB anymore. Second, as a test, trying adding any other control to your view in the XIB, say a UIButton. Can you see that when you launch your app?

Comment: That's very odd, something has happened to my xcode or something, even when I add a UIButton or resize buttons in the XIB, it doesn't update in the sim. Any idea what's up with that?